# How to refresh ViewController code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller with a table with custom row (image and text).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustomRow";
    CustomRow *cell = (CustomRow *)[_default dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomRow" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    x = x + 1;
    trovato = [util cerca:giorno :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", x]];
    if ([trovato isEqualToString:@"NO"]) {
        cell.pallino.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"grigio.png"];
    } else {
        cell.pallino.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"verde.png"];
    }
    cell.title.text = [right objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

This work correct the first time I open the View controller, when I tap on a row I have to open a another view controller and I do some changes. When I come back with Navigation bar I want that the table refresh again the image (the most important things), but I cannot do this. What I have to do????

Thanks

Comment: [self.tableview reloadData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData)

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh your table view (`reloadData`) when you come back from you sub view, e.g. in your `viewWillAppear` function.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you tap on row save indexpath for that row
2. You make chanhes in detailviewcontroler (your next view controller which open after row press)
3. when you come back check
4. if there are change then reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: method to reaload that cell else do nothing (as you did not do any changes)
   To check if you have made any changes on detailviewcontroler or not you can use delegation or with simplest approach reload selected row always when you cam back from detailviewcontroler.
   you can refresh cell in 
   `-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` by using saved indexpath

Comment: There is not need reload all cells in tableView, just reload cell which is need to refresh its content, its efficient way

Comment: I tried, I read the correct row, I found the changes, but the image of the row not change.

Comment: You should update datasource of UITableView before calling reloadRowsAtIndexPaths i.e. right (your datasource refered from line `cell.title.text = [right objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`) also should be modified when it comes back from detailviewcontroler

Comment: I do this:

    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    
        CustomRowDieta *cell = (CustomRow *)[_default cellForRowAtIndexPath:row];
        trovato = [util cercaPastoDieta:giorno :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 7]];
        if ([trovato isEqualToString:@"SI"]) {
            cell.pallino.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"verde.png"];
        }
        cell.title.text = [right objectAtIndex:row.row];    
        [dietaPasto reloadData];
     }

I have to add something??

Comment: do something like this   `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { [right      replaceObjectAtIndex:savedindexpath.row withObject:newObject];           [dietaPasto reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:savedIndexapth] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];  }`   in above code newObject is data which is uodated by DetailViewContorler

Comment: What is NSArray arrayWithObject ? and what is the effect of [right      replaceObjectAtIndex:savedindexpath.row withObject:newObject] ??

Comment: Please go through [THIS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:) and [THIS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:) for clear idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following ways,it just use it on `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

or

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathOfYourCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

hope this will work